# How to add a DirectX reference in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, directx

How can I add a DirectX reference to my C# project in Visual Studio 2010?
Thanks.

Comment: Post on GameDev with more / up to date information: [Can I use DirectX with C#?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/62839/can-i-use-directx-with-c)

Answer (score 13):

1. Go to the solution explorer
2. Click references
3. Click add reference
4. Click Browse
5. Browse to:

   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\DirectX for Managed Code\1.0.2902.0\
6. Select your directX package.

Comment: Managed DirectX has been abandoned/deprecated for some time now.

Answer (score 5):

There is one way i have find. First you need to install **DXSDK** (i have June2010 and SDK for Windows 7). Go to  "*Add reference*" dialog press "*Browse*" , go to somthing like this `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\DirectX for Managed Code\1.0.2902.0` or `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Managed DirectX\v9.02.2904` then choose proper dll for example - `Microsoft.DirectX.dll`. So you can add "*using Microsoft.DirectX*" directive to your project. All done.

Answer (score 4):

DirectX is for unmanaged code - C++. To use it from C# you need to find a wrapper library for it. The two best right now are [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org) and [SharpDX](http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/). Grab the binaries from the sites and just add a reference to them.

Comment: but i do it on visual studio 2008 ?!?!?

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand that...

Comment: There are managed directx 9.0 libraries for c# from Microsoft as well

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Windows API code pack from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack.  Then, look at the article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msaleh/archive/2009/08/25/introducing-directx-features-of-windows-api-code-pack.aspx, and you should be started.  (the article talks about VS2008, but it works on VS2010 too)

Good luck....

Answer (score 0):

We use managed directx too. You should download DirectX Software Development Kit:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c72d9f1e-53f3-4747-8490-6801d8e8b4ef

Dlls for using DirectX in managed code have included into it.

Comment: i install DirectX SDK ! and i can do this on vs 2008 but in vs 2010 there isn`t any item for DirectX !

Comment: You'll probably have to change the target framework to 2.0.