# C# Playing an AVI

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, media-player, media, avi

I want to play an AVI video in my WInForm. I'm not worried about Codec(s). We'll install them on the client with a group policy.

The video plays great in Windows Media player but having to tell people to "Click Start, My Computer, Network Share, Sub-Folder, etc" is complicated over the phone. The idea is to make a C# App that plays the video within the app.

(For those who argue, why not put shortcuts on the desktop)
We can do that but people delete shortcuts or their desktop is way too cluttered. So I want to make a quick app that displays the list of video's (via ComboBox) and plays the selected video within the App. The video's path should be on the server instead of "bundling" the video inside the app.

Thanks

--- The question is what do I need to do to play the video (code, tutorial links, etc).

--- Based on Rajesh's code
I get the following error

```
Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v1.1.4322' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.
```

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with Windows 7 and the June 2010 Direct X SDK. I had to browse to the dll in the C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Managed Code for DirectX folder and search each subfolder for that class.

Comment: OK. And what is the question?

Comment: The app could simply ShellExecute the WMV file? Of course there are movie-player components if you want it embedded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [DirectX SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=2c7da5fb-ffbb-4af6-8c66-651cbd28ca15) from Microsoft for .Net

It contains a AudioVideoPlayback namespace with the Video class that is easy to use in any .Net project. You bind the Video class to a Panel control like this:

```
Video video;

public Form1(string[] args) {
    InitializeComponent();

    video = new Video(dialog.FileName);
    video.Owner = panel1;
}
```

The video class contains several methods for playback like Play, Pause, Stop and of course FromFile.

More information on using the AudioVideoPlayback namespace in C# can be found at:

- [AudioVideoPlayback API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb324497%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Video Class (Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms902629.aspx)

Comment: Where do I find the Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback? I've downloaded the SDK and installed it. Will it be under .NET, COM or do I need to browse the dll

Comment: You need to browse to the dll

Comment: It doesn't get automatically? So do I need to add each Direct X component seperately? I thought the SDK Installer would take care of this for me

Comment: Rajesh - Can you please comment on your code a little more? I am a little confused why you set the owner to a Panel? Do I need a Panel in my UI? Please don't skip any steps in your explaination. I'd appreciate your help

Comment: You dont need a panel. Its just the control in which your want to play the video is set via the owner property on the video object. Refer to the msdn documentation

Comment: I downloaded and installed the SDK and can not find anything in it relating to this.  Couldn't find anything like the AudioVideoPlayback in the SDK.

Comment: @JeffReddy: Have you looked at the MSDN link about AudioVideoPlayback(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb324497%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I know this is late, but in case anyone's wondering how to add the AudioVideoPlayback to references: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414474/how-to-add-a-directx-reference-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: Isn't AudioVideoPlayback deprecated? I believe you should probably be using the Windows Media Player Activex Control if you want to use .NET managed code or for low level unmanaged you should probably be using Media Foundation (some would argue that DirectShow is still okay although according to MS MF is their advertised future (although they are still wishy washy at times

Comment: Warning: Microsoft DirectPlay has been deprecated. Deprecated components of Microsoft DirectX 9.0 for Managed Code are considered obsolete. While these components are still supported in this release of DirectX 9.0 for Managed Code, they may be removed in the future.

Answer (score 3):

[Using the Windows Media Player Control with Microsoft Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There's a good .NET wrapper for directshow, you can use it: http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/

Another alternative, that can make the retrieval of videos out of the net easy is use the WebBrowser control, and then incorporate a flash/html5 video player within.